# Не загружается библиотека во время отладки основного проекта

Tags: c#, visual-studio, отладка, .net-5, .net-standard

У меня есть 3 проекта:

1. `Xamarin forms`
2. `.NET Core(backend)`
3. `.NET Standar библиотека`

Библиотека подключена к обоим проектам. Когда я работаю с проектом `Xamarin` у меня не возникает проблем с отладкой проекта библиотеки, но когда я работаю с `.NET Core` проектом, получаю сообщение

> "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded
> for this document"

Все танцы с бубном, которые я нашел, все перепробовал. [Все способы описанные тут - я попробовал.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been)

Что нужно сделать, что бы во время отладки проекта на `.NET Core` я мог отлаживать подключенную к нему библиотеку?

P. S. Изначально библиотека создавалась в решение с проектом `Xamarin`.

Comment: NET Standard какой версии? `Не загружается библиотека` или загружается, но не отлаживается? .NET Core какой версии?

Comment: Возможно, к Замарину подключен _проект_ в виде исходников, а к .net core подключена _библиотека_ в виде dll?

Comment: @aepot загружается, но точки остановки святятся как не загруженные в отладку

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov к .net подключена как проект в зависимостях, в окне отладки я вижу что собираются оба проекта при старте отладки

Comment: Отключить [Just My Code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2022)?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Just My Code мне лично не мешает отлаживать подключенные бибилиотеки к проекту, скорее всего дело не в этом.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov just my code tun off - это первое что я сделал, не помогло :(

Comment: @aepot может вывести в отдельное решение попробовать?

Comment: Без понятия, мы разговариваем об абстрактных дотнетах в вакууме, версий вы не дали, попробовать нет возможности.

Comment: @aepot .NET Standard 2.1 это Xamarin и библиотека и .NET 5 .NET Core

Comment: @aepot это может быть связано из за разных версий фреймворка? Библиотека .NET Standart 2.1 а Core .NET 5?